# Navigate to child of lazy loaded module angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'updateBooking', loadChildren: () => import('./update-booking/update-booking.module').then(m => m.UpdateBookingModule) },
  { path: 'booking', loadChildren: () => import('./booking/booking.module').then(m => m.BookingModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

lazy loaded Booking module's routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'bookingdashboard' },
  {
    path: 'bookingdashboard', component: BookingDashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'associateinfo' },
      {
        path: 'associateinfo', component: AssociateInfoComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'agenda', component: AgendaComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'zone', component: ZoneComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BookingRoutingModule { }
```

I am on associate info page with url `http://localhost:4200/booking/bookingdashboard/associateinfo`
From this page when I try to navigate to `agenda` page using `this._route.navigate(['../agenda' ]);` I am getting error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'agenda'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'agenda'`

However If I try to navigate from HTML file using `[routerLink]="[ '../agenda']"` its navigating to agenda page

Comment: Did you tried `this._route.navigate(['booking/bookingdashboard/agenda'])` ?

Comment: What is Difference Between this two component 'BookingDashboardComponent' and 'AssociateInfoComponent'

Comment: You are using two Component on same route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are navigating to only component specific route path, you should follow route as  module-path/component-path

```
this._route.navigate(['booking/bookingdashboard/agenda' ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
this._route.navigate(['/booking/bookingdashboard/agenda']);
```

Answer (score 1):

> After the link parameters array, add an object with a relativeTo
>   property set to the ActivatedRoute. The router then calculates the
>   target URL based on the active route's location.

```
constructor(private _router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
this._router.navigate(['../agenda'], { relativeTo: this.route })
```